# Why navbar from jquery mobile and phonegap app does not show up?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

My navbar simply does not work. It does not show up at the screen, I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

I'm doing a mobile app using JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

Bellow you will find all my index.html file with all the all stuff I am referencing.

I'm using the phonegap Cli(command line) and I'm testing in a browser for now.

Code bellow:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mycss.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>

        <!--<script type="text/javascript">
            //app.initialize();
            xyz.initialize();
        </script>-->
        <title>xyz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-hole="page" id="Page1">
            <div data-hole="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>xyz</h1>
                <div data-hole="navbar">
                <ul>      
                    <li><a href="#index" data-icon="home">Home</a>      
                    <li><a href="#contacts" data-icon="search">Contacts</a>      
                    <li><a href="#events" data-icon="info">Events</a>      
                    <li><a href="#news" data-icon="grid">News</a>    
                </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-hole="content">
                <button onclick="showPopup()">Show Popup</button>
            </div>
            <div data-hole="footer">
                My Footer
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>-->
        <!--<div class="xyz">
            <div data-hole="footer">
                <div data-hole="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid">Summary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-active">Favs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Setup</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>-->


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your code it is `data-role` and not data-**hole**.

**HTML:**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="Page1">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>xyz</h1>
                <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>      
                    <li><a href="#index" data-icon="home">Home</a>      
                    <li><a href="#contacts" data-icon="search">Contacts</a>      
                    <li><a href="#events" data-icon="info">Events</a>      
                    <li><a href="#news" data-icon="grid">News</a>    
                </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <button onclick="showPopup()">Show Popup</button>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                My Footer
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Problem solved! (I'm feeling like a need to use a glass!)

Comment: It happens :). do accept the answer if it worked for u, so the question does not add to unanswered list.